# Select only date form datetime field in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stored this kind of format  **2022-02-06 18:40:00** in my **trans_reminder_date**. I want to use only date in where condition but with this condition i am not able to fetch data

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

SELECT * FROM sales_detail 
   WHERE  trans_reminder_date = '".$today."' 
   AND trans_reminder_date != ''
   ORDER BY sales_detail_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will give you all the result for the current date. By doing this there won't be any need to cast values.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sales_detail
WHERE
    trans_reminder_date >= curdate()
    AND trans_reminder_date < curdate() + INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER BY
    sales_detail_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If when your filter parameter is a string:

```
select * from sales_detail  
where cast(trans_reminder_date as date) = cast('2020-03-22' as date)
```

if you want to use the current date for filtering then MySQL has a function that getting only the current date without time.

```
select * from sales_detail  
where cast(trans_reminder_date as date) = curdate()
```

On MySQL for converting other types to another, you can use a `cast`

P.S.
Starting with MySQL 8.0.13 we have now an easiest way to create functional indexes. When you are using `cast(updated_at as date)` then DB will not use index for column `updated_at`. You must create a functional index for best performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cast function to change datetime type to date example

```
Cast(column_name as date)
```

Or
You using convert function change datetime type to date

```
CONVERT(column_name, date);
CONVERT(expression, datatype);  
OR,  
CONVERT(expression USING character_set);
```

character_set: It specifies the desired character set in which we want to be converted.

Data type : It specifies the desired data type in which we want to be converted.

Expression : It is a specified value going to be converted into another specific datatype.